# How to return sum from Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I need to get sum of the value field from Expense object and display this in textview, but I really don't know how to do it in Room Database. I need to create specific query in Dao or there is some other way?

Pojo:

```
@Entity(tableName = "expense_table")
public class Expense {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private String note;
private Double value;
private String type;
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface ExpenseDao {

@Insert
void insertExpense(Expense expense);

@Query("SELECT * FROM expense_table")
LiveData<List<Expense>> getExpensesByDay();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new query in DAO

```
@Query("SELECT COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(value,0)), 0) From expense_table")
LiveData<Double> getTotal();
```

Comment: What about the sum in query? I need to create that field in pojo?

Comment: the `sum` is a reserved keyword and is used to get the sum of the field. In the query you will get total sum of all `value` column in the database